# Can an object injected InSingletonScope be also injected in a multi-binding elsewhere?

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, ninject

I need to bind `ICommand` to a specific implementation *when injected exactly into* a specific type (by naming convention), and then I also need a multi-binding for a type that has an `IEnumerable<ICommand>` constructor parameter - and that one needs to receive the same instances, since I need my commands *InSingletonScope*.

I tried this, among other things:

```
// note: ICommandMenuItem naming convention for [Foo]Command: [Foo]CommandMenuItem
var item = types.SingleOrDefault(type => type.Name == commandName + "CommandMenuItem");
if (item != null)
{
    _kernel.Bind<ICommand>().To(command)
           .WhenInjectedExactlyInto(item)
           .InSingletonScope()
           .DefinesNamedScope("commands");

    _kernel.Bind<ICommand>().To(command)
           .WhenInjectedExactlyInto<ConfigurationLoader>()
           .InNamedScope("commands");
}
```

But every time I break into the constructor for `ConfigurationLoader`, the `IEnumerable<ICommand>` parameter contains no elements. Same with or without the named scope, which I *thought* I needed to tell Ninject "look I have these two bindings for the same type, and I want you to give me the same instance for both".

The first binding works - I know because my menu items do something when they're clicked. But something is wrong with the way `ICommand` is (not?!) injected into `ConfigurationLoader`, and I'm not sure how to fix it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As far as i can see named scope makes no sense here:

- `DefinesNamedScope` defines the root of a named scope
- `InNamedScope` makes sure there's only one instance of `T` in the dependency-tree of the root. It also means it's getting disposed once the root object is garbage collected.

When you want all your commands to be in Singleton scope then don't use another. Also, as long as the `ConfigurationLoader` is not a (transient) dependency of the menu item, the `InNamedScope` would never be fulfilled, anyway.

Also, `InSingletonScope()` is applied per binding. I.e. if you have two bindings for the same type, `InSingletonScope()` will (might) result in two instances. Thats why there's the `Bind(Type[])` overload, where you can bind multiple service to one resolution.

What you need to have is a single binding with an `OR` condition:

```
// note: ICommandMenuItem naming convention for [Foo]Command: [Foo]CommandMenuItem
var item = types.SingleOrDefault(type => type.Name == commandName + "CommandMenuItem");
if (item != null)
{
    _kernel.Bind<ICommand>().To(command)
           .WhenInjectedExactlyIntoAnyOf(item, typeof(ConfigurationLoader))
           .InSingletonScope();
}
```

Now, of course, the `WhenInjectedExactlyIntoAnyOf` is not available. Plus, sadly enough, ninject does not come with an out of the box way to combine existing conditions. So, you've got to roll your own condition, based on `When(Func<IRequest,bool> condition)`.

---

There is a slightly hackish way to combine existing `When...` conditions.
One can first create the binding, without any condition, then add a condition, retrieve it (it's a `Func<IRequest,bool>`), and then replace the condition, retrieve it, combine it, replace it... and so on...

```
// example binding without condition
var binding = kernel.Bind<string>().ToSelf();

// adding an initial condition and retrieving it
Func<IRequest, bool> whenIntegerCondition = binding.WhenInjectedInto<int()
    .BindingConfiguration.Condition;

// replacing condition by second condition and retrieving it
Func<IRequest, bool> whenDoubleCondition = binding.WhenInjectedInto<double>().
    BindingConfiguration.Condition;

// replacing the condition with combined condition and finishing binding
binding.When(req => whenIntCondition(req) || whenDoubleCondition(req))
       .InSingletonScope();
```

Comment: Thanks for this, it helped clear a bit of the fog around what's actually happening when I configure a binding. Would you have any idea about why it wouldn't work? (`binding.When(request => whenCommandMenuItemCondition(request) || whenConfigurationLoaderCondition(request)).InSingletonScope();`) -- or should I ask a new question? (the constructor is *still* receiving an empty `IEnumerable<ICommand>`)

Comment: Something else must be going on, I get an empty `IEnumerable<ICommand>` *regardless* of what I do; even dropping the singletonscope and going with `_kernel.Bind<ICommand>().To(command).WhenInjectedExactlyInto(item);` and  `_kernel.Bind<ICommand>().To(command);` doesn't give me the expected multi-binding.

Comment: Ha, got it - I'm actually loading the configuration (i.e. calling that constructor) *before* the `ICommand` bindings are made.